# Get image url in prestashop

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I need to make a feed for my site for a comparing site. It has to be a sql statement.
For now I have this:

```
select  pl.name as Titel,
    ROUND(p.price*1.21,2) as Price,
    replace(concat('http://', ifnull(conf.value,'domain/'), cl.name, '/', p.id_product, '-' , pl.name, '.html'),' ','-') as Link,
     concat('http://', ifnull(conf.value,'domain'), '/img/p/', p.id_product, '-' , pi.id_image, '.jpg') as "Image-location",
     cl.name as Categorie,
    p.id_product AS ID
from dbrb_product p
left join dbrb_image pi on p.id_product = pi.id_product
left join dbrb_product_lang pl on p.id_product = pl.id_product
left join dbrb_category_lang cl on p.id_category_default = cl.id_category
left join dbrb_configuration conf on conf.name = 'dbrb_SHOP_DOMAIN'
left join dbrb_product_carrier x on p.id_product = x.id_product
group by p.id_product
```

But now with the new prestashop version 1.6 the image doesn't work anymore.

Now the image path is: domain.com/img/p/number/number/number/image.png
I don't get the logic from it, can somebody tell me?

There is also another problem I have to deal with, because there are some products which have the same image.

Can somebody complete the SQL code or help me further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is simple, replace concat from your query for this one:

concat('http://', ifnull(conf.value,'example.com'), '/img/p/',SUBSTRING(pi.id_image from -4 FOR 1),'/',SUBSTRING(pi.id_image from -3 FOR 1),'/',SUBSTRING(pi.id_image from -2 FOR 1),'/',SUBSTRING(pi.id_image from -1 FOR 1),'/' , pi.id_image, '.jpg') as product_image,

Comment: Can you please add an explanation as to why you think this is an answer? As it is, this answer is just a line of code that means very little by itself.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the SQL code to get all possible product details including correct urls of the images:

```
SELECT p.id_product AS 'ID',
pl.id_lang AS 'ID_LANG',
p.active AS 'Active (0/1)',
pl.name AS 'Name',
p.id_category_default AS 'Default Category',
p.price AS 'Price tax excl.',
p.id_tax_rules_group AS 'Tax rules ID',
p.wholesale_price AS 'Wholesale price',
p.on_sale AS 'On sale (0/1)',
p.reference AS 'Reference #',
p.quantity AS 'Quantity',
pl.description_short AS 'Short description',
pl.description AS 'Description',
pl.meta_title AS 'Meta-title',
pl.meta_keywords AS 'Meta-keywords',
pl.meta_description AS 'Meta-description',
pl.link_rewrite AS 'URL rewritten',
pl.available_now AS 'Text when in stock',
pl.available_later AS 'Text when backorder allowed',
p.available_for_order AS 'Available for order',
p.date_add AS 'Product creation date',
p.show_price AS 'Show price',
p.online_only AS 'Available online only',
p.condition AS 'Condition',
concat( 'http://YOUR-URL.com/img/p/',mid(im.id_image,1,1),'/', if (length(im.id_image)>1,concat(mid(im.id_image,2,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>2,concat(mid(im.id_image,3,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>3,concat(mid(im.id_image,4,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>4,concat(mid(im.id_image,5,1),'/'),''), im.id_image, '.jpg' ) AS url_image
FROM ps_product p
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_image im ON p.id_product = im.id_product
WHERE 1=1
and p.active = 1
```

Comment: How can I add each image in columns? and not separated by commas?

Answer (score 2):

The number in the paths to an image is the digits of its ID, for example image with ID 121 will have the following path:

```
http://domain.com/img/p/1/2/1/121.jpg
```

However, MySQL doesn't have any built-in functions to do this (AFAIK), so you will need to build a user-defined function.

Answer (score 1):

Mh, im using this:
          `concat('http://', ifnull(conf.value,'example.com'), '/img/c/', c.id_category, '.jpg') as url_image,`

it works perfect.

Comment: How can I add each image in columns? and not separated by commas?

Answer (score 1):

The image path is based on the image id. You split all the digits and add a slash between them to get the folder where the image is stored.

```
-- build the image path
CONCAT('http://',
        -- get the shop domain
        IFNULL(conf.value, 'undefined_domain'),
        -- the path to the pictures folder
        '/img/p/',
        -- now take all the digits separetly as MySQL doesn't support loops in SELECT statements
        -- assuming we have smaller image id than 100'000 ;)
        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(pi.id_image) >= 5, 
            -- if we have 5 digits for the image id
            CONCAT(
                -- take the first digit
                SUBSTRING(pi.id_image, -5, 1),
                -- add a slash
                '/'),
            ''),
        -- repeat for the next digits
        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(pi.id_image) >= 4, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(pi.id_image, -4, 1), '/'), ''),
        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(pi.id_image) >= 3, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(pi.id_image, -3, 1), '/'), ''),
        if(CHAR_LENGTH(pi.id_image) >= 2, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(pi.id_image, -2, 1), '/'), ''),
        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(pi.id_image) >= 1, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(pi.id_image, -1, 1), '/'), ''),
        -- add the image id
        pi.id_image,
        -- put the image extension
        '.jpg') as image_url
```

Comment: How can I add each image in columns? and not separated by commas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the prestashop class "IMAGE" instead of loading MySql with functions

```
public static function getImgFolderStatic($id_image)
```

Returns the path to the folder containing the image in the new filesystem

It strips the number of the image into the subfolders used by prestashop.

Example:

```
foreach($SQLresult as $key=>$value)
   {
      $imageUrl=_PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_.Image::getImgFolderStatic($value['id_image']).$value['id_image'].".jpg"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here $productID is your product's ID :)

```
$prod = new Product($productID);
$imgArray = $prod->getImages('1');
if (count($imgArray)>0) {
    $imgID = $imgArray[0]["id_image"];
    $imageUrl=_THEME_PROD_DIR_.Image::getImgFolderStatic($imgID).$imgID.".jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer from SunnyBoy, I have written this, which also generates the friendly URL for the product (I have tested it with PrestaShop 8.1.1):

```
SELECT 
    p.id_product AS 'ID',
    pl.id_lang AS 'ID_LANG',
    p.active AS 'Active (0/1)',
    pl.name AS 'Name',
    p.id_category_default AS 'category_id',
    cl.link_rewrite AS 'category_urlslug',
    concat( 'https://example.com/', cl.link_rewrite, '/', p.id_product, '-', pl.link_rewrite, '.html') AS 'product_url',
    p.price AS 'Price tax excl.',
    p.id_tax_rules_group AS 'Tax rules ID',
    p.wholesale_price AS 'Wholesale price',
    p.on_sale AS 'On sale (0/1)',
    p.reference AS 'Reference #',
    p.quantity AS 'Quantity',
    pl.description_short AS 'Short description',
    pl.description AS 'Description',
    pl.meta_title AS 'Meta-title',
    pl.meta_keywords AS 'Meta-keywords',
    pl.meta_description AS 'Meta-description',
    pl.link_rewrite AS 'URL rewritten',
    pl.available_now AS 'Text when in stock',
    pl.available_later AS 'Text when backorder allowed',
    p.available_for_order AS 'Available for order',
    p.date_add AS 'Product creation date',
    p.show_price AS 'Show price',
    p.online_only AS 'Available online only',
    p.condition AS 'Condition',
    concat('https://example.com/img/p/',mid(im.id_image,1,1),'/', if (length(im.id_image)>1,concat(mid(im.id_image,2,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>2,concat(mid(im.id_image,3,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>3,concat(mid(im.id_image,4,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>4,concat(mid(im.id_image,5,1),'/'),''), im.id_image, '.jpg') AS 'image_url'
FROM ps_product p
    INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
    INNER JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON p.id_category_default = cl.id_category
    LEFT JOIN ps_image im ON p.id_product = im.id_product AND im.cover = 1
and p.active = 1;
```